# Prolog: 'Hello world' resulting in existence_error. Have checked file paths with no success

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

Here is my file:

[image: image of notepad]

Here is proof of where the file is located:

[image]

Here's what I typed into the GNU Prologue console:

```
| ?- change_directory('C:/Users/Aidan/Desktop/Prolog practice').

yes
| ?- [hello_world].
```

Expected result:

```
compiling C:/Users/Aidan/Desktop/Prolog practice/hello_world.pl for byte code...
```

Actual result:

```
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(source_sink,'hello_world.pl'),consult/1)
```

I have tried different file names, different folders, using the "`consult`" command, and using the absolute path instead of the filename. All result in the same error. Please help?

Comment: What does [`working_directory(?atom)`](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec262) say?

Comment: Maybe your file is actually named `hello_world.pl.txt` and Windows Explorer is hiding you the `.txt` extension

Answer (score 1):

Windows native notepad is a simple text editor which tends to put `.txt` at the end of filenames. I suggest you to install another editor (e.g. notepad++).

Under Windows, gpolog allows you to consult a file with the File|Consult menu option which allows you to select the wanted file in a file selector dialog box. Then it emits a `consult` showing the real filename (check if there is a `.txt` a the end).

You can obviously consult it with passing the full pathname:

```
['hello_world.pl.txt'].
```

It is however better to rename your file with the extension `.pl` (or `.pro`). (The windows explorer has an option to hide known file extensions, maybe deactivate it to see full filenames including their extensions).

BTW, gprolog does not handle well spaces in filenames. I suggest you to rename your `Prolog practice` directory as `Prolog-practice`.